# Is there a way to map a Map to a List in Dart?

Tags: dart

I want to turn a map into a list of objects that contain information from the key and value of each map entry.

I know it is possible to do it this way:

```dart
myMap.map<String,Widget>((key, value) {
    return MapEntry<String, Widget>(key,Widget(
        //Some widget that uses key and value
    ));
}).values.toList();
```

However, I am wondering if there is a simpler way to do it without turning it into a map first. Something like:

```dart
myMap.map<Widget>((key, value) {
    return Widget(
        //Some widget that uses key and value
    );
});
```

However this returns an error:
"Error: Expected 2 type arguments."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correct, you can map [`.entries`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.3.0/dart-core/Map/entries.html) instead, like this:

```
myMap.entries.map((e) => Widget( /* use e.key and e.value */ )).toList()
```